# VBA (Excel) Get height of printable page

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a macro that edits my excel document by setting page breaks at border lines of merged cells before printing the document. But a problem that has arisen is that some merged cells are higher than the max size of a page. So I have to split the merged cells into two (or more) cells to make them fit. Now, I don't know in advance what formatting the user of my script will have and therefore what page type will be used. So I need to get the height of the current page type somehow but I can't figure out a way to do it. Here's my latest attempt:

```
Private Sub Cellsize(i)
    Dim H As Double
    H = Worksheets("Summery table").PageSetup.PaperSize.Height
    If Cells(i, 1).MergeArea.Height > H Then
        Call FixLastingPageBreaks
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is happening with the code as you have it currently and how is this different from what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Option Explicit
Sub testing2()

   Dim wb As Workbook
   Set wb = ThisWorkbook

   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

   Dim paperSize As Long
   paperSize = ws.PageSetup.paperSize  '9

   Select Case paperSize

    Case 9

    MsgBox "Name: is xlPaperA4, Value: 9, Description: A4 (210 mm x 297 mm)"

    'Case .......

   End Select


   MsgBox ws.PageSetup.Orientation '1

End Sub
```

You can use a Select Case or similar construct to convert the number returned to the constant or to link to size. You can then assign values to variables as necessary or point to constants you have defined.

Object browser lists the constants and you can see the number at the bottom or grab from

[XlPaperSize Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241398(v=office.12).aspx) and

[XlPageOrientation Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241397(v=office.12).aspx)

[image: Object model PaperSize Constants]

Comment: So your suggestion is to make a case for every pre-existing XlPaperSize Enumeration right?
I guess that works but how do I translate centimeters (or inches) to whatever length excel is using for row/cell heights?
Thanks for your detailed response!

Comment: that is one way where you could have it as a Function which returns an array (for example) of the dimensions.

Comment: So there is no way of simply getting the height value currently used? For example, what if the papersize is user defined?

Comment: I will have a look and see if i can dig anything else up